# Where should I store the photos before sending Web service?

Tags: android, web-services, storage

I have an app which has to take photos, I want to store them before send them via web service, but I don't know where I have to store them, External, Internal or Cache Storage??? What would be the Best Practice here?

In the same screen I want yo see all the photos I have uploaded, and I have the same question, When I open the screen and connect to web service and download all the photos, where I have to save them??

Greetings.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html - read up and decide which is what you want. Also consider the target Android versions. Internal storage is an issue for older variants.

Comment: @323go I'm not sure yet. I want to store it during a short time, before send it via web service, and then delete it (maybe cache), but I don't want to have problems with the space (maybe external), and I don't want it be accesible (maybe internal). Thanks!